# Retrieve floating point value from modbus register using jamod api

Tags: java, modbus

I'm trying to retrieve data from Modbus register using Jamod. I need data in IEEE floating point format. I have tried the following code:

```
private float getData (String  address, int count) {
        float sum = 0.0f;

        request = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(Integer.parseInt(address), count);
        response = new ReadMultipleRegistersResponse();
        request.setUnitID(1);
        response.setUnitID(1);
        request.setHeadless();

        try {

            response = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) execute(connection, holdingRequest);

            for ( int i=0; i<registerCount; i++) {
                sum = sum + response.getRegisterValue(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sum;
    }

private ModbusResponse execute(SerialConnection connection, ModbusRequest request) {        
        try {
            transaction = new ModbusSerialTransaction(connection);
            transaction.setRequest(request);
            transaction.execute();
            return transaction.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But every time I get some random values. I searched online and found this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.InputRegister). I have tried solution in the link but I'm getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a proper data type to retrieve your value, as register size is 16 bit, you should use 16 bit to store it.

In your case use this code:

```
try { 
    response = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) execute(connection, holdingRequest); 
    for ( int i=0; i<registerCount; i++) {
        sum = sum + (short) response.getRegisterValue(i);
    } 
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.